# Why isn't my quill stem controlling the front wheel of my bike?

Tags: headset

Please excuse me if some of my terminology is off. I don't know much about bikes. 
When I came home from college I noticed that the seat of my bike was way to high and the headset was really low, I have a old style quil stem head set,. So I decided to raise the headset. When I raised the headset I did not know that I was not supposed to completely remove the headset stem bolt. I tried screwing it back in but it doesn't work. So now the headset does not control the front wheel, and I have no idea how to fix it. Can someone PLEASE help me!!! I also have a question, why is it that when I hit the bicycle stem bolt with a hammer it fixes it but only for a short time period?

Comment: Duplicate of  http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/21360/14414

Comment: I just have one more question. Why is it that when I hit the bicycle stem bolt with a hammer it fixes it but only for a short time period?

Comment: You mean hitting the quill with a hammer?

Comment: I'm hitting the stem where the stem bolt is that connects the headset to the wheel.

Comment: wild guess: you deformed the quill by hitting it with a hammer. This (small) deformation is enough to hold the quill in place within the (fork) steerer tube. But not strong enough to permanently fix the quill in the steerer tube

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Completely remove the bicycle quill
2. Hang the bike up-side down
3. Take out the wedge. If the wedge is stuck, try inserting the quill bolt alone (no quill, just bolt). Take care not to push the wedge further in. Try to thread in the wedge, and remove the wedge when there is enough grip.
4. If wedge is truly stuck, remove the front wheel from the fork. The fork should have a hole so that you can push the wedge from below (with rod/hammer)
5. Re-assemble the quill and wedge with the bolt correctly. Make sure you know how to do this, it should be straight-forward.

Good luck

Bicycle terminology (regarding quill stem, which often seen in old bicycle):

- Wedge (sometimes 'Expander'): a device that wedge/expand the quill inside the fork steerer tube. This is achieved via compression of the wedge/expander into the quill, using a quill bolt.
- Quill: a device connecting (fork) steerer tube and stem. Usually the stem and the quill comes together as one part.
- Stem: a device connecting the handlebar to the fork (via quill).